# My laptop's fan overrun. CPUs temperature is extremly high

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

My fans make loud noises all the times. CPUs reach 93 degrees at times.

My Laptop is an HP pavilion g6-2300 bought in May 2013. It has Ubuntu 17.04 with an SSD. Last time I cleaned the internal parts was less than a year ago. It generally overheats very easily with any kind of process running but since nowadays everything is done through browsing (I use latest version of Firefox) it seems that just browsing makes it quite hot.

This is the output for `TOP`

```
top - 19:55:37 up 1 day,  7:35,  2 users,  load average: 1,82, 1,39, 1,18
Tasks: 216 total,   1 running, 215 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 34,6 us,  5,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 59,4 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  7627072 total,   240080 free,  6632328 used,   754664 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 14146552 total, 13960912 free,   185640 used.   606048 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 3136 alessio   20   0 3405472 799336 112104 S  15,2 10,5  99:01.26 firefox     
 3321 alessio   20   0 4061336 1,358g  69664 S  11,6 18,7  69:27.22 Web Content 
 2528 alessio   20   0 1657944 291792  28472 S   8,9  3,8  39:57.55 compiz      
 1640 root      20   0  643716  90616  49896 S   8,6  1,2  41:08.69 Xorg        
 3327 alessio   20   0 3862076 936252 102780 S   8,3 12,3  70:16.45 Web Content 
 3372 alessio   20   0 3440468 878480  67668 S   7,6 11,5  47:15.09 Web Content 
16869 alessio   20   0 1622720  83228  40188 S   5,0  1,1   5:19.76 plugin-con+ 
 2473 alessio   20   0 4042276  12208   9804 S   4,3  0,2   7:41.82 pulseaudio  
 3276 alessio   20   0 3715680 939212  75776 S   4,3 12,3  63:05.20 Web Content 
20222 alessio   20   0  686696  37068  29116 S   1,7  0,5   0:00.75 gnome-term+ 
 2138 alessio   20   0  378416  16612   5156 S   1,3  0,2   1:29.19 ibus-daemon 
 2157 alessio   20   0  494376  20932  13468 S   0,7  0,3   0:25.11 ibus-ui-gt+ 
 2368 alessio   20   0  468636  24248  15048 S   0,7  0,3   0:34.79 bamfdaemon  
20243 alessio   20   0   44196   3708   3052 R   0,7  0,0   0:00.51 top         
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   1:44.66 rcu_sched   
  816 root      20   0 1094336   6072   3916 S   0,3  0,1   0:08.75 repowerd    
 2064 alessio   20   0   46792   4724   2872 S   0,3  0,1   0:36.32 dbus-daemon
```

What should I do? Should I install heat sink or any other device? If yes, could you suggest me one?

Comment: This seems like a hardware question more than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more information. Does this happen all the time? Only when doing certain things? Did it always happen or did it start recently? How old is the laptop? **Have you ever cleaned it?** Is the issue specific to Ubuntu or does it happen with other operating systems?

Comment: To see if some process runs amok run `top` on the command line to see if any process is consuming constantly around 100% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the screen info stuff but from a mechanical point of view, assuming that the fan and heat-sink are clean, and that the air vents are all clear, I'd try replacing the heat-sink paste. I use MX-4 myself, it made a big difference to an old laptop of mine.

Another tip: stick bigger feet on the bottom of your laptop to make sure there's plenty of air flow. Web browsing is very CPU intensive so if it's a small one it'll be maxed-out and running hot most of the time.